# efficiently rewriting (rebase -i) a lot of history with git

Tags: perl, git, git-rebase

I have a git repository with about 3500 commits and 30,000 distinct files in the latest revision.  It represents about 3 years of work from multiple people and we have received permission to make it all open-source.  I am trying hard to release the entire history, instead of just the latest version.  To do this I am interested in "going back in time" and inserting a license header at the top of files when they are created.  I actually have this working, but it takes about 3 days running entirely out of a ramdisk, and still does require a little bit of manual intervention.  I know it can be a lot faster, but my git-fu is not quite up to the task.

The question: how can I accomplish the same thing a lot faster?

What I currently do (automated in a script, but please bear with me...):

1. Identify all of the commits where a new file was added to the repository (there are just shy of 500 of these, fwiw):

   ```
   git whatchanged --diff-filter=A --format=oneline
   ```
2. Define environment variable GIT_EDITOR to be my own script that replaces `pick` with `edit` only a single time on the first line of the file (you will see why shortly). This is the core of the operation:

   ```
   perl -pi -e 's/pick/edit/ if $. == 1' $1
   ```
3. For each commit from the output of `git whatchanged` above, invoke an interactive rebase starting just before the commit that added the file:

   ```
   git rebase -i decafbad001badc0da0000~1
   ```

My custom GIT_EDITOR (that perl one-liner) changes `pick` to `edit` and we are dropped to a shell to make changes to the new file.  Another simple `header-inserter` script looks for a known unique pattern in the header that I'm trying to insert (only in known file types (*.[chS] for me)).  If it's not there, it inserts it, and `git add`'s the file.  This naive technique has no knowledge of which files were actually added during the present commit, but it ends up doing the right thing and being idempotent (safe to run multiple times against the same file), and is not where this whole process is bottlenecked anyways.

At this point we're happy that we've updated the current commit, and invoke:

```
    git commit --amend
    git rebase --continue
```

The `rebase --continue` is the expensive part.  Since we invoke a `git rebase -i` once for every revision in the output of `whatchanged`, that's a lot of rebasing.  Almost all of the time during which this script runs is spent watching the "Rebasing (2345/2733)" counter increment.

It's also not just slow.  There are periodically conflicts that must be addressed.  This can happen in at least these cases (but likely more):  (1) when a "new" file is actually a copy of an existing file with some changes made to its very first lines (e.g., `#include` statements).  This is a genuine conflict but can be resolved automatically in most cases (yep, have a script that deals with that).  (2) when a file is deleted.  This is trivially resolvable by just confirming that we want to delete it with `git rm`.  (3) there are some places where it seems like `diff` just behaves badly, e.g., where the change is only the addition of a blank line.  Other more legitimate conflicts require manual intervention but on the whole they are not the biggest bottleneck.  The biggest bottleneck is absolutely just sitting there staring at "Rebasing (xxxx/yyyy)".

Right now the individual rebases are initiated from newer commits to older commits, i.e., starting from the top of the output of `git whatchanged`.  This means that the very first rebase affects yesterday's commits, and that eventually we'll be rebasing commits from 3 years ago.  Going from "newer" to "older" seems counter-intuitive, but so far I'm not convinced that it matters unless we change more than one `pick` to an `edit` when invoking the rebase.  I am afraid to do this because conflicts do arrive, and I don't want to deal with a tidal wave of conflict ripples from trying to rebase everything in one go.  Maybe somebody knows a way to avoid that?  I haven't been able to come up with one.

I started looking at the internal workings of git objects [1](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)! It does seem like there should be a much more efficient way to walk the object graph and just make the changes that I want to make.

Please note that this repository came from an SVN repository where we effectively made no use of tags or branches (I already `git filter-branch`ed them away), so we do have the convenience of a straight-line history. No git branches or merges.

I'm sure I've left out some critical information, but this post already seems excessively long. I will do my best to provide more information as requested.  In the end I may need to just publish my various scripts, which is a possibility. It is my objective to figure out how to rewrite history thusly in a git repository; not to debate other viable methods of licensing and code release.

Thanks!

Update 2012-06-17: [Blog post](http://jonmccune.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/code-release-history-and-aesthetics-with-git-filter-branch-and-friends/) with all the gory details.

Comment: It's pretty obscure for me, i never needed to do a massive history rewrite, but i know that the correct tool to do it is [`git filter-branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/git-filter-branch.html). I'm sorry i can't be more helpful, i hope it gets you on track.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: I used `filter-branch` prior to starting all of this rebasing to eliminate (filesystem) paths that were irrelevant to this release. (The SVN repository from which this git repository was created is even larger and more unwieldy.)  However, you may have a point that scripting changes to be made during a `filter-branch` could be more efficient than doing all of this rebasing.  I will investigate.

Comment: `It represents about 3 years of work from multiple people and we have received permission to make it all open-source`, i know it's of-topic, but i'm curious :P, what's the project name/homepage?

Comment: It is a research hypervisor and some associated applications.  I'll try to remember to come back and post a link once we have one. Thanks for the interest! :)

Comment: The code is available from: http://xmhf.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter '[[ -f README ]] && echo "---FOOTER---" >> README' HEAD
```

Would essentially add a footer line to the `README` file, and the history would look like it has been there since file creation, i'm not sure if it will be efficient enough for you but it is the correct way to do it.

Craft a custom script and you'll probably end up with a good project history, doing too much "magic" (rebase, perl, scripted editors, etc) may end up losing or changing project history in unexpected ways.

[jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516647/jon) (the OP) used this basic pattern to achieve the goal with significant simplification and speedup.

```
git filter-branch -d /dev/shm/git --tree-filter \
'perl /path/to/find-add-license.pl' --prune-empty HEAD
```

A few performance-critical observations.

- Using the `-d <directory>` parameter pointing to a ramdisk directory (like `/dev/shm/foo`) will improve the speed significantly.
- Do all changes from a single script, using its built-in language features, the forks done while using small utilities (like `find`), will slow the process many times. Avoid this:

  ```
  git filter-branch -d /dev/shm/git --tree-filter \
  'find . -name "*.[chS]" -exec perl /path/to/just-add-license.pl \{\} \;' \
  --prune-empty HEAD
  ```

This is a sanitized version of the perl script the OP used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use File::Slurp;
use File::Find;

my @dirs = qw(aDir anotherDir nested/DIR);
my $header = "Please put me at the top of each file.";

foreach my $dir(@dirs) {
  if (-d $dir) {
    find(\&Wanted, $dir);
  }
}

sub Wanted {
  /\.c$|\.h$|\.S$/ or return; # *.[chS]
  my $file = $_;
  my $contents = read_file($file);
  $contents =~ s/\r\n?/\n/g; # convert DOS or old-Mac line endings to Unix
  unless($contents =~ /Please put me at the top of each file\./) {
    write_file( $file, {atomic => 1}, $header, $contents );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like it's moving in the right direction.  One thing that is unclear to me is why this doesn't introduce `---FOOTER---` once for every commit after the file README exists.  Where in the "smarts" of `--tree-filter` does git figure out to only run that command once? For example, `git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'echo "i ran">>/tmp/ran.log' HEAD` prints "i ran" once for every commit to that temporary file.

Comment: That's how `filter-branch` works, it "loops" trough all commits of the branch you specified. And you actually have to chance all the commits, you can't escape that, `git` doesn't store `diff`s, it store files contents, so if you have a `A--B--C` history, add "footer" to commit `A` but no `B`, it's like you deleted it in `B`, it doesn't spread, so if you wanna keep your "footer" through all the history, you'll have to add it to commits `A`, `B` and `C`, just like `filter-branch` does (running for every commit).

Comment: Thanks very much for this explanation.  I was able to accomplish my goal using `git filter-branch --tree-filter`, and created a single short (less than 20 lines) perl script to make the desired changes. My understanding is that stackoverflow best practice is to edit your answer to clarify how to address my specific question, upvote, and mark as solved.

Comment: Independently of the script's performance optimizations, if you're ever doing this again and looking for an easy boost, consider AWS. You can pick up an on demand cluster compute instance for $2.40 / hour. I once used one to filter-branch 35 different repositories into a single repository. Work machine? 10 hours deep before I quit the script. AWS cluster compute instance running 60.5 GB of RAM and 88 compute units? One hour, ten minutes, and cheaper than a fast food lunch.

Answer (score -1):

The blobs are content addressable.  You can't modify a single file in isolation without changing its hash, which changes the directory blob referenced by any commit that includes it, and thus any commits that descend from it.  Basically you have to rewrite the world, as I understand the problem.  I guess I can imagine an algorithm that did all this work in reverse DAG order, with a big hash table of original-to-modified object hashes, that rewrote each object only once.

If you already have a correct solution (even one that takes three days), is it really worthwhile to try to optimize this?  I **can't** imagine actually getting this code debugged and working correctly enough to release the results in less than the three days that the naive solution would take.

Comment: In 3 days you can do sooo much more things than rewriting a repo's history, it's not Cray computer era. So yes it's optimizeable INMHO

Comment: I meant it would take more than three days of **development** before the result was ready for release.

Comment: Sorry, misread things, can you edit your post so that I can remove my downvote?