# After rewriting Git repo history, the old commit history is still visible

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I've used [efficiently rewriting (rebase -i) a lot of history with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917835/efficiently-rewriting-rebase-i-a-lot-of-history-with-git) to replace file text (`Copyright <author>` to `Copyright <company>`) for the entire commit history of a Git repository. It works, but the *old* commit history is **still visible**.

In the screenshot below, the 'new' history in the blue branch comes after the unwanted 'old' history in the purple branch. How do I get rid of the 'old' history? (why it doesn't 'merge' into one continuous history beats me!

[image: after <code>git filter-branch</code> command]

Comment: `HEAD` actually is a pointer to the commit that is currently checked out. It doesn't mean the beginning of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that GUI is SourceTree, by Atlassian. And it was correct. The issue was that I had other branches and tags referencing the "old history". So naturally, it sticks around!

Think in terms of Back to the Future :)

So, "you can't rewrite history" is partly correct, it just depends on your perspective.

**Doc Brown:** Obviously the time continuum has been disrupted, creating a new temporal event sequence resulting in this alternate reality.

**Marty:** English, Doc!

**Doc Brown:** Here. Here, let me demonstrate. Let's say that this line represents time. [draws straight line and points to places] Here's the present 1985, the future and the past. Obviously, somewhere in the past the timeline skewed down into this tangent (branch) [draws new line and writes 1985A] creating an alternate 1985 (master). Alternate to you, me, and Einstein, but reality for everyone else. Recognize this? [shows Blast from the Past bag (tag)] It’s the bag the sports book came in; I know because the receipt (tag) was still inside. I found them in the time machine...along with this! (more tags)

Yay! Git is BTTF!

Moral: Delete the references and it will cease to exist!

Comment: Just make _sure_ the rewriting went well, and nothing got lost/mangled in the process.

Comment: Yes. I copy the clone (clone the clone?) and test everything out. If it breaks, I just delete the directory, unzip and try again.

Comment: better copy (as a directory), that way you are sure no unstaged files or other stuff gets lost if you decide to switch to the copy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a simpler, faster alternative to `git-filter-branch` specifically designed for rewriting files from Git history. One way in which it makes your life easier here is that it actually handles *all* references by default (all tags, branches, etc) but it's also [10 - 50x](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsR1d5Zpes8HdER3VGU1a3dOcmVHMmtzT2dsS2xNenc) faster.

You should carefully follow these steps here: http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage - but the core bit is just this: download the [BFG's jar](http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/#download) (requires Java 6 or above) and run this command:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --replace-text replacements.txt  my-repo.git
```

The `replacements.txt` file should contain all the substitutions you want to do, in a format like this (one entry per line - note the comments shouldn't be included):

```bsh
pa$$word   # Replace literal string 'pa$$word' - with '***REMOVED***' by default
Copyright Volte==>Copyright MegaCorp     # Replace, specifiying replacement text
regex:Copyright \w+==>Copyright MegaCorp                # Replace, using a regex
regex:Copyright (\d{4}) \w+==>Copyright $1 MegaCorp     # Replace with reference
```

Your entire repository history will be scanned, and any non-binary files (under 1MB in size) will have the substitutions performed: any matching string (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be replaced.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the tip. I will definitely check this out.

Comment: I could not find the `replacements.txt` file content format nowhere in the documentation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rewrite a git history.  This isn't an authority thing, nobody's refusing to implement it, it's something that simply cannot be done. A commit id is a unique name for that specific commit.  Any different commit, due to any change anywhere in its contents or its history or its description,  has a different id.  Your 'master' tag (a branch is just a tag that git uses as an implicit parent and updates when you `git checkout` it  and commit something new) now refers to the new history you made with rebase (edit: err, more likely with filter-branch here).  Your 'svn/trunk' tag still refers to the original history.  If you want to forget svn/trunk in your repo, `git branch -d svn/trunk`.

Comment: Then why are there reports of people doing this very thing? For example, placing a License in the header of every file from the start of the project?

Comment: @Volte You'll hear people discussing "rewrites" of history but you've just demonstrated why that's the wrong word to use: people think of it as a single, destructive act that actually alters what's already there.  What's actually being done is what you did: add a new history that's just like the old one except with a bunch of changes, then pretend the new one _is_ the old one and forget what was there before.  Your repo has everything except the forgetting part done.

Comment: Ah. And so how do I "extract" my "new" history and push only it to my server (I haven't pushed yet, remember I'm moving from svn).

Comment: You've got your new history on the 'master' branch, the old one on 'svn/trunk', there's nothing unusual about either of them. When someone clones from your repo they're likely to take the 'master' branch as their start poitn, that's what most people look for.  What goes on in whatever svn repos you want to talk to, that's a different issue.